# TypeError: s.indexOf is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I have a reservation app where every time the user clicks on a date the seats are either occupied or not whether the seat was previously reserved for that day or not. In the back end I am using firebase. The logic is that every time the user picks a date I send an array of objects back to the back with the id of seats and whether true or false for occupied. I am using redux as well, so I have an action for processing that array. The data is stored in nested collections.

```
export const updateSeatByDate = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();

            id?.forEach(element => {
                firestore.collection('Building1').doc('Floor1').collection('Seats1').doc(element).update({
                    occupied: id.occupied
                }).then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATED_SEATS'})
                }).catch((err) => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATED_SEATS_ERROR', payload: err})
                })
            })
    }
}
```

The action should loop through all documents and should update each seat with either true or false for occupied. Now, every time I pick a date I get the following error:
**TypeError: s.indexOf is not a function**
Does anybody have any suggestion for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code calling `indexOf` of an object? It seems you haven't included all relevant code.

Comment: In the function where I set up the array for the back end. But I just realized where was the problem. All I had to do was to convert the id to string before I put it into the firestore query. It looked like before that:
firestore.collection('Building1').doc('Floor1').collection('Seats1').doc(id).update
Now it looks like that:

firestore.collection('Building1').doc('Floor1').collection('Seats1').doc(String(id)).update

But now I get a different error: 
Seats updated error FirebaseError: Requested entity was not found.